# UTF-8 in Rails on Mac OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, encoding

We recently ran into the requirement of accepting UTF-8 characters in one of our models. We set up the field to use the proper encoding in the database (mysql, locally mariadb in my case). We all run Mac OSX, with a terminal with the proper encoding set (as far as I know).

Currently I'm seeing this behaviour:

- My terminal accepts pasted UTF8 characters. irb or rails console does not
- When setting the field to contain a UTF8 character in the database, I can call Model.last and see this character just fine in rails console. The model is not valid.
- The tests which pass on my colleague's computer run fine, they fail on mine. The test, as well as the model files have `# encoding: utf-8` on the first line
- This is the validation: `validates_format_of :name, with: /^([[ßàáâãóôþüúðæåïçèõöÿýòäœêëìíøùîûñé]\d[a-z]-]+){3,}$/`
- the test loops over an array with allowed and disallowed characters, checking if the result is valid. These all fail with no apparrent error
- When entering a UTF8 character via the browser, this validation also fails

I am currently at a loss as to where to look. Any ideas are appreciated.

For what it's worth:

`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` are present in my .zshrc

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > Encoding.default_internal
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
2.0.0p0 :002 > Encoding.default_external
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 



$> locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: I don't know mariadb, but looking here: https://kb.askmonty.org/en/character-sets-and-collations/ I don't see any mention of Unicode . . . and in fact this https://kb.askmonty.org/en/utf8mb4-utf16-and-utf32-support/ implies it is not properly support. How have you set up your dev db to support unicode?

Comment: @NeilSlater we've set the charset and collation to UTF-8, just the way it is in production and with my colleagues. When getting the record set in the database directly via rails console, I can see that specific character. The queries in the database work fine, it seems to be the rails side that's acting up...

Answer (score 0):

We (mostly my colleagues) managed to track this down. It turns out the \d we use in our regexp  was in fact location sensitive in Ruby 2.0.0-p0

Solved by installing p195

I believe this is mentioned in the changelog (but I'm not sure it's exactly this change that solved it):

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/05/14/ruby-2-0-0-p195-is-released/

## 7972 Regexp POSIX space class is location sensitive.

Comment: funny detail: the \d was removed moments after discovering the bug. We meant to match 0-9, and not the numerical characters in other languages